# Reference Shared Silverlight Assembly with slsvcutil.exe

Tags: silverlight, wcf, svcutil.exe, service-reference

I have several WCF services being consumed by different Silverlight applications. I am currently using **slsvcutil.exe** with a pretty standard setup to generate my Silverlight proxy objects:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\microsoft sdks\silverlight\v4.0\tools\slsvcutil.exe" http://myhost/MyService.svc?wsdl /out:Proxy.cs /edb /namespace:"*,My.Namespace" /ct:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1 /r:"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50524.0\System.Windows.dll"
```

What I would like to do is **share some types**, specifically a base `RequestMessage`, `ResponseMessage`, and `ApplicationFault` between the multiple services and their generated Silverlight proxies. I would like these types to be in their own common Silverlight namespace so that I can use shared Silverlight code to do things poll a service request or check for a SOAP fault and translate it into a known exception type that can be thrown.

I thought that this could be done by using the **/r** or **/reference** switch on slsvcutil.exe by specifying the path to the DLL with the shared types. I tried building the proxy like this but it still seemed to be generating new incompatible types for the objects I was trying to share:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\microsoft sdks\silverlight\v4.0\tools\slsvcutil.exe" http://myhost/Service.svc?wsdl /out:Proxy.cs /edb /namespace:"*,My.Namespace" /ct:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1 /r:"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50524.0\System.Windows.dll" /r:"C:\path\to\MySharedTypes.dll"
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong? Or do I have the wrong impression of what the **/r** switch can be used for with slsvcutil.exe?

Comment: Can you show us the source code for Service.svc, MySharedTypes.dll, and also the generated client proxy object?

Comment: Long time ago I know, but did you ever solve this? I have the same problem.